# Changing nodes in XSLT based on context

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have one XSL file that I wanna include or use in two different contexts. In one of the contexts I want to use 'fo:block' but in the other context I want to use 'div class="Block"'.

Is there someway to change all my 'fo:block' in my XSL to 'div class="Block"' or vice versa based on the context, maybe with the use of parameters?

Comment: Can you explain what a "context" means? Is that a node in the input you can match on? And I supposed if you want to create either `fo:block` or `div`, it doesn't stop there but you rather want to output either XSL-FO or HTML. It seems easier maintaining two different stylesheets or write one stylesheet with one mode for XSL-FO output and a second mode for HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple condition:

```
<xsl:variable name="outputformat" select="'html'"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$outputformat = 'html'">
        <div class="Block">
            <!-- your html code -->
        </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:block>
           <!-- your normal code -->
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Alternatively you can make a second xsl document and copy every node except the

```
<fo:block/>
```

which you should change to

```
<div class="block"/>
```

This would look like:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'block'">
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="class" select="'Block'"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In the first example you wrote, all my code will be the same in my "html code" and my "normal code", so if I do that one I will have to have the exact same code twice except in the first one I will use div class=block and in the second on I will use fo:block. Which is what I wanna try and avoid.

Based on context i want all content wrapped in either fo:blocks or div class="block". So basically some smart way to search and replace i guess? in my xslt. If that makes sense.

Comment: Well, if you want to have 2 different outputs, you have to do it twice...
"Is there someway to change all my 'fo:block' in my XSL to div class='Block'"
The lower example takes the fo output, changes the fo:block to div and saves it into another file. Thats the way to do it.

Comment: Btw. you dont have to copy your code twice. I assume you are working with match templates and that you are not hardcoding everything. Just put <xsl:apply-templates/> instead of the "your code" comment in there.

Comment: Some of it unfortunately has to be hard coded or actually most of it.

Comment: In that case you can still use a <xsl:template name="dothings"> and call it twice like a function in other languages. You call it with <xsl:call-template name="dothings"/>.